# adjusting a blog feed

Tags: xml, rss

So, this is what I have so far. I've had a request to shorten posts so that more can show up at once. I need to find a way to limit the content text to one paragraph. Is there a post string that can do this? Thank you in advance for your consideration.

```
    var feed1 = new google.feeds.Feed("http://example1/atom.xml");
    feed1.load(function(result) {
      if (!result.error) {
        var container = document.getElementById("feed1");
        var postString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
          var attributes = ["title", "link", "publishedDate", "content"];
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var linkText = entry[attributes[1]];
            var titleText = entry[attributes[0]];
            var dateText =  entry[attributes[2]];
            dateText = dateText.substring(0,16);
            var contentText = entry[attributes[3]];
            postString += "<h2><a href='";
            postString += linkText;
            postString += "'>"
            postString += titleText;
            postString += "</a></h2><p>";
            postString += contentText;
            postString += "<a href='";
            postString += linkText;
            postString += "' class='view-more'>read more</a>";
            postString += "</p>";
            container.innerHTML = postString;
        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: How long is a paragraph?

Comment: I'd say around 70 to 90 words give or take.